# JHipster why do I need to start frontend manually?

Tags: npm, jhipster

I don't get why should I run `npm start` and then `mvnw`? 
I started up the app using `mvnw` and I would like to register user, which fails, nonetheless I see the email in log. When I tried the url to activate I got 404(freshly created app). I have read some hints that I have not started `npm start`.

I don't get why do I need to start the frontend separately and moreover on different port (:9000). My guess is that is for reloading the SPA, so I will have 2 SPA one on 8080 that was built during `mvnw` and second on 9000 which will be sinced with my changes to Angular code. But which is to correct port to run account/activate against?

**UPDATE**

The link has been wrong http://127.0.0.1:8080/account/activate?key=Jn1AveHVguG5BBeCjDNc should be http://127.0.0.1:8080/activate?key=Jn1AveHVguG5BBeCjDNc. In this particular case I am using vue blueprint so maybe the issue is there(created [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/issues/510))

Comment: did you check the browser console errors?may be node modules are not installed properly

Comment: I don't see any errors. Should I run the url against 8080 as generated in email or against 9000?

Comment: you should access the url shown in console after run mvnw. default  its 8080..delete node_modules and build again.

Comment: This is another problem I am stuck with I not able to make it run with maven-frontend-plugin so I need to skip it's invocation. Otherwise I'm getting error which I am not able to resolve `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project vue: Could not extract th
e npm archive: Could not extract archive: 'd:\repository\com\github\eirslett\npm\6.13.0\npm-6.13.0.tar.gz': Expanding package/node_modules/define-p
roperties/.editorconfig would create file outside of d:\projects\my\jhipster\vue\node\node_modules`

Comment: remove all packages in local maven repo..in here  $HOME .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\  and try to rebuild.

Comment: I tried that already. Strange thing is that the tar file contains inside `package` module on top not `npm`. Another thing is that yesterday I have been able to create another demo app , which has been working properly until I decided to delete node and node-modules folder. After that it stopped working. With the same npm extract error

Comment: It can be fixed using this [steps](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9545#issuecomment-481283172) which is hack not solution

Comment: Also using front-end-maven plugin in version 1.8.1-SNAPSHOT fixes this. But still the url /account/activate?key=Jn1AveHVguG5BBeCjDNc return 404